# Clicking button in AlertDialog made in onOptionsItemSelected crashes emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My main question is: Is there anyway I can get trigger an AlertDialog from inside onOptionsItemSelected() without it crashing my emulator when I press a button on the dialog?

I have looked all over the internet for this but everyone I find keeps saying the same thing but even when I copy and paste their code I get the same error. So I'll try explain my situation as well as I can.

Here is an example of a pretty simple AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Your Title")
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
```

Now this WORKS. As long as I run it OUTSIDE of the onOptionsItemSelected() function. For example, if I add this piece of code inside the onClickListener for a regular Button. Then the alert dialog will appear when I click the button and everything will work. However when I include this piece of code inside my onOptionsItemSelected(). Then the alert dialog will appear, but pressing a button on the dialog will crash my entire emulator. Here is my onOptionsItemSelected():

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_trash:

            Log.i("trash", "button clicked");


            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Your Title")
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

            return true;
        case R.id.action_help:

            Log.i("help", "button clicked");

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now when I click on the item in my toolbar linked with the action_trash id. I get an alert dialog, but when I click the OK button, my entire android emulator just crashes. And the only warning I can still see is this:

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
EmuGL:WARNING: bad generic pointer 0x7fc16d378600
```

Which I am pretty sure is an unrelated message. I sometimes see people asking for LogCats, but there are none that I can find since the entire emulator has crashed.

And as a side question: why doesn't this even work at all? Is it because the onClickListener() made inside setNeutralButton() has somehow been destroyed? I am fairly new to android, so if this is some big nooby mistake that can be avoided in the future any advice would be appreciated.

P.S. I have also tried replacing '.Builder(this)' with '.Builder(MainActivity.this)' and all the variations I have encountered so far and none of them solve the issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you try it on a device to see what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ran into this same thing. Two separate things worked for me.

1. Changing the AVD settings to have "Software - GLES 2.0" instead of hardware or auto for the "Emulated Performance" option.
2. Turn on "Show Layout Bounds" in the developer options of the AVD.

Either of those should fix the issue, you don't need to do both.

Comment: Thank you so much. These seemed to have fixed my problem, at least I know that it won't crash on an actual device. My only issue now is that the Software - GLES setting makes the emulator perform very poorly, and the Show Layout Bounds makes it hard to evaluate the UI. Is there anything I can do it to increase performance with Software GLES?

Comment: Unfortunately I ran into the same issue of the poor performance. I opted for the hardware/auto setting and layout bounds for times when I had to work on that particular part of the app. Sorry I'm not much more help there =/

Comment: Alright well you've been a great help anyway :D I was losing my mind over this issue and I'm glad there is at least some sort of workaround. I've marked this as the accepted answer as there really isn't much to be found on the internet on this issue.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you and glad to be of help. Enjoy your deving!

Comment: you saved my headache thnxx man @xero Software solution worked for me! :)